# C++ template declaration that restricts specializations too much

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, specialization

I'll try to explain my current problem briefly. It could be solved easily but the only solution I've found until now doesn't satisfy myself, maybe you'll indicate to me the next level of indirection that would be needed for resolution.

I use CRTP here, even if that's not the crux of the issue. Here is a piece of code that reproduces my problem :

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
    public:
        static void p()
        {
            T::p();
        }
};

template <typename T>
class B
{
    public:
        static void q()
        {
            T::q();
        }
};



????? template <??????> ???? // How to declare C here ??? 
class C;


//now first specializations with A
template <int a>
class C<a> : public A<C<a> >
{
    public:
        static void p()
        {
            //specific stuff
        }
};

template <int a, typename Other_handlers ...>
class C<a, Other_handlers...> : public A<C<a, Other_handlers...> >
{
    public:
        static void p()
        {
            //specific stuff
        }
};

template <int a, typename Child>
class C<a, B<Child> > : public A<C<a, B<Child> > >
{
    public:
        static void p()
        {
            //specific stuff
        }
};



//second specializations with B
template <int a, int b>
class C<a, b> : public B<C<a, b> >, C<a>
{
    public:
        static void q()
        {
            //specific stuff
        }
};

template <int a, int b, typename Other_handlers ...>
class C<a, b, Other_handlers...> : public B<C<a, b, Other_handlers...> >, C<a>
{
    public:
        static void q()
        {
            //specific stuff
        }
};

template <int a, int b, typename Child>
class C<a, b, B<Child> > : public B<C<a, b, B<Child> > >, C<a>
{
    public:
        static void p()
        {
            //specific stuff
        }
};
```

The goal of this piece of code would be to have some methods in `C` that depends on template parameters (here `C<1,2>` would have methods of both `A` and `B` class, whereas `C<1>` would only have ones of `A`, then `C<1, C<1,2> >` would have only ones of `A`, whereas `C<1, 2, C<3> >` would have both, etc ...).
Where I fail is at the declaration of C before its specialization, because I don't know how to declare something that would be generic enough to support both values and type template parameters (in this case int values and types, mixed).
Because if I declare

```
template <typename ... Args>
class C;
```

it obviously fails parsing ints.

And

```
template <int a, int b, typename ... Args>
class C;
```

obviously fails parsing types in specialization with only one `int` parameter.

So, the only solution I've found until now is to declare 2 different types instead of `C` :

```
template <int a, typename ... Args> // allows first specialisations
class C;
template <int a, int b, typename ... Args> //allows second specialisations
class D;
```

But I would like to group into only one declaration. Is it possible ?

Thank you in advance !

PS : By the way the title I chose is very bad, if you have any better suggestion for it let me know !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I can imagine is declare `C` as receiving only types

```
template <typename ...>
class C;
```

and wrap the initial integer values in a dummy type (or using `std::integer_sequence`)

```
template <int ...>
struct Ci
 { };
```

Obviously a declaration of `C` as (by example) `C<1>`, previously

```
C<1> c1;
```

become

```
C<Ci<1>> c1;
```

The following code is ugly but compile

```
template <typename> class A {};
template <typename> class B {};

template <typename ...>
class C;

template <int ...> struct Ci {};

template <int a>
class C<Ci<a>> : public A<C<Ci<a>>>
 { };

template <int a, typename ... Other_handlers>
class C<Ci<a>, Other_handlers...> : public A<C<Ci<a>, Other_handlers...>>
 { };

template <int a, typename Child>
class C<Ci<a>, B<Child>> : public A<C<Ci<a>, B<Child>>>
 { };

template <int a, int b>
class C<Ci<a, b>> : public B<C<Ci<a, b>> >, C<Ci<a>>
 { };

template <int a, int b, typename ... Other_handlers>
class C<Ci<a, b>, Other_handlers...>
   : public B<C<Ci<a, b>, Other_handlers...>>, C<Ci<a>>
 { };

template <int a, int b, typename Child>
class C<Ci<a, b>, B<Child> > : public B<C<Ci<a, b>, B<Child> > >, C<Ci<a>>
 { };


int main ()
 {
   C<Ci<1>>  c1;
 }
```

Comment: And how to instantiate `C` in this case? Something like `C<1> c;` will probably yield an error.

Comment: @VTT - the old `C<1> c;` become `C<Ci<1>> c;`; maybe is the case to add this in the answer; thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of ugly solution involving macro which only allows you to group resulting type usage into a single declaration:

```
template<int V> struct
fooIntImpl
{
};

template<int V> fooIntImpl<V>
foo_deduce_helper(void);

template<typename T> struct
fooTypeImpl
{
};

template<typename T> fooTypeImpl<T>
foo_deduce_helper(void);

#define foo(template_parameters) decltype(foo_deduce_helper<template_parameters>())

int main()
{
    foo(42) fooint;
    foo(int) footype;

    return 0;
}
```